# Excel 2010 VBA creates weird named data range upon import of delimited text data

Tags: excel

I am importing a pipe delimited text file into an excel spreadsheet using a query method that I found online. The code works beautifully and fast, however, it creates a weird named range every time I run it. The issue is I cannot seem to find a valid method of deleting the range using VBA, I can only delete using the name manager. Here is my code:

```
Function doFileQuery(fileName As String, outSheet As String) As Boolean

    Dim rootDir As String

    rootDir = "W:\Development"

    Dim connectionName As String

    connectionName = "TEXT;" + rootDir + "\" + fileName

    With Worksheets(outSheet).QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connectionName, Destination:=Worksheets(outSheet).Range("A5"))

        .Name = fileName
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    End With
    doFileQuery = True
End Function
```

Here is the weird named range created:
_11r_3_Eastdata_FrankLaRoccaMonths_c_4

Here is how I am trying to delete it:
ThisWorkbook.Names("_11r_3_Eastdata_FrankLaRoccaMonths_c_4").Delete

When VB hits the above statement it gives me a

Run Time Error '1004':

Application defined or Object defined error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe it's a worksheet-level name.  Try `ActiveSheet.Names("_11r_3_Eastdata_FrankLaRoccaMonths_c_4").Delete`

Comment: @pnuts, Not at all! I like getting credit when I get it right :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a worksheet-level name. Try:

`ActiveSheet.Names("_11r_3_Eastdata_FrankLaRoccaMonths_c_4").Delete`